# Opening ASP.NET app in 2 different sessions at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Is there any chance to write logic in asp.net app so that the app can be opened in two differemt sessions simulataneously.i.e,My app has button "Open in new session".so whn i click the button it opens the app again in new window.But the session is shared between the two windows.Is there any way to stop this?Please suggest

Comment: Which browser and version you are using??

Comment: I am using IE9 browser.

Comment: If your session depends on Cookies all browser Windows will always share one session. Nothing to do here.

Comment: My sessiond ependa on a dropdown value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" cookieless="true">
```

or

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" cookieless="UseUri" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true">
```

cookiless is the option which says browser to store the session key in cookie or not. In above option it will not store the session id in cookie rather it will append different session id in url.

Comment: should i write that in web.config?

Comment: were you able to do this?

Comment: I did it.But still the session is shared between two windows.

Comment: can you paste the config session setting here.

Comment: <system.web>  
      <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" cookieless="true"></sessionState>
    </system.web>

Comment: When you launch the new window , do you see the new session id appended to the url?

Comment: My "Open new session" button click code is       protected void btnnewsession_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( '../Default.aspx', null, 'height=700,width=760,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=no,location=yes,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true);
        }

Comment: So when i click that button,the app should be opened in a new window with a new session

Comment: It should be.Code is ok, config is ok. I created on sample asp.net application and I could see the session is not shared.Either you try with one test application or I will send you the test app by evening and you can compare and check the mistake done.

Comment: Okay!Thanks.I will wait for your test app

Comment: let me know your email address.

Comment: Let me know if sample helped you or not.

Comment: I couldnot open the rar file in my system.I have written the sessionState tag inside another syste.web tag and that worked.No when i click the "Open new session" button new window with new session(sessioid)appended to URL comes up.But now the thing is in the old window when i navigate to another page ,new session is being appended.Please tell me how to maintain the old session constant.

Comment: New session means, the new window session?

Comment: No.In the same old window.So now when i click the "open in new session" button,i have my app open in 2 windows,one old and one new.I need new session only when i open the new window.When i do cookieless=true,in the old window,when i go to some other page,that also opens in new session which should not happen.Please let me know if you need some more explanation

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to store a unique identifier value (preferably a GUID) as a session-id in the view-state of the page. Since view-state is stored in the page two pages will always store different GUIDs. You can also store the date and time stamp of the last time that page was posted/generated on the server and there by maintain a timeout if your logic requires it.

Comment: Please tell me how i can write it in the button click event.If possible please provide with sample logic

Comment: Can you tell me if you are storing any data in the session that you will be accessing?